# Getting fatal error due to a nil in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Using Xcode, Im getting a fatal error due to a nil received in swift 2.0. The constant declared below is the point where the app crashes because the mediaItem response is nil:

```js
let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: (self.mediaItem?[0].url)!)
```

how can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Not a swift expert by any measure, but I think you'll find the answer in this tutorial. http://www.codingexplorer.com/the-guard-statement-in-swift-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is happening due to `(self.mediaItem?[0].url)!`. If the `self.mediaItem?[0].url` returns a `nil` value then the statement changes like: `(nil)!` and crashes the application. Also you need to handle the array out of bounds exception, that can occur if your mediaItems array is empty.

You can fix it like:

```
if let mediaArray = self.mediaItem where mediaArray.count > 0
{
   if let urlString = mediaArray[0].url
   {
     let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString)
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Midhun, but the error persist `Array index out of range`

Comment: @Edu: This issue is due to the array count is zero. Please check my updated answer

Comment: thanks @Midhun, but to avoid the issue is to use the distinct operator if `self.mediaItem?.count != 0`